# Core Data Undo/Redo - Action depends on what was undone

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, undo-redo

I have  a somewhat complex data model in my iPad application (an OpenGL drawing app), and I'm working on implementing undo/redo functionality. I like the fact that Core Data will undo data model changes for free, but I don't know if the built-in functionality will be sufficient for me.

I have seen lots of examples of undo/redo being implemented in drawing apps, however they generally do the following:

1. Tell the managed object context to `undo`.
2. Redraw *everything* on the page from the changed data model.

This is horribly inefficient - in my app I need to be able to perform an action to undo based on the particular object that is being 'undone', and often this means refreshing only part of the canvas.

So my question is this: can I register my own undo operations and use that in conjunction with the built-in undos? For example, say I do the following when the user draws a line:

```
- (void)drawLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint
{
    // Register the undo operation.
    [[[managedObjectContext undoManager] prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] 
                                               removeObjectWithIndex:nextObjectIndex];

    // Draw the line object.  
    [self drawLineObjectWithIndex:nextObjectIndex fromPoint:startPoint toPoint:endPoint];

    // Save the new object to the data model.
    [MyCoreDataHelper saveLineObjectWithIndex:nextObjectIndex fromPoint:startPoint toPoint:endPoint];

    nextObjectIndex++;
}
```

When I come to undo this action, will the invocation be fired **and** the model changed appropriately? Or does this situation require that I abandon the built-in managed object context undo system and roll my own using just the `NSUndoManager`, including deleting and editing the data model myself? Unless I can tell what the built-in undo/redo is actually undoing, it looks like this could get horribly messy and complicated...

**Edit:** I suspect (if the idea above was to work) I would need to wrap it into an undo group, so that my registered undo operation would be grouped with the data model changes?

**Another Edit:** Also, can I guarantee the order in which undo actions will be carried out? In other words, if I call `undo` after the core data changes are saved and my undo action is registered, can I be sure that a deleted entity will be reinstated before my undo action is called?

Comment: If you only need to refresh part of the canvas, can't you use - (void)setNeedsDisplayInRect:(CGRect)invalidRect

Comment: No, for a number of reasons. Firstly, my drawing is done using OpenGL. Also, the drawing operations involve lengthy calculations to find every point sprite location, and even if I had these precalculated for every drawing stroke, it could take too long to render all the strokes for the entire screen. Do you know then if it is possible to identify what data was changed from the undo? Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know then if it is possible to identify what data was changed from the undo?

Why don't you check out the notifications for `NSManagedObjectContext` [(Apple Docs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html)

Specifically look at the notification's *userInfo* with the keys `NSInsertedObjectsKey`, `NSUpdatedObjectsKey`, and `NSDeletedObjectsKey`.

> Also, can I guarantee the order in which undo actions will be carried out?

Well, undo works via stack (last in, first out), so you "*should*" be able to trace your steps. Obviously you have to be very specific in the order you register your undos if you want things to unfold correctly. A few lines of code that help me trace the undo stack just to see what is behind the veil of mystery:

```
id undoStack, redoStack;
object_getInstanceVariable(undoManager, "_undoStack", &undoStack);
object_getInstanceVariable(undoManager, "_redoStack", &redoStack);
NSLog(@"%@", [undoStack description]);
NSLog(@"%@", [redoStack description]);
```

[(Props to this site for the above code)](http://parmanoir.com/Inspecting_NSUndoManager%27s_undo_stack)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I'll try some things out and give an update on my progress.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `flyweight` structure. [It is generally used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) for undo/redo operations. What you're asking requires you to do this yourself.

Flyweights can store as much data as you want, and you can remove them from your undo sequence whenever you want. Your flyweights, for example, could store the pixel data before each edit was made. This would take large amounts of memory, but you could easily undo something without redrawing the entire scene.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There's no way I'm going to try and store pixel data - this could use several MBs of memory after potentially only a small number of drawing strokes. I already have a means of undoing/redoing individual strokes by manipulating OpenGL vertex buffer data; I have tested it and know it to be efficient. My problem is that I can't implement a generic "just redraw the screen" kind of approach - I need to be able to say: "Oh, the user just undid an eraser stroke... I'll call the -undoEraserStroke: method".

Comment: The Flyweight structure allows you to append different kinds of flyweights to the flyweight chain. It's very convenient for undo, and granted a valid method for undo/redo of vertex buffer data, you could create a flyweight chain very easily.

There's also the ArrayList<E> worth looking into. It's an indefinitely extendable array of any type (declaring int by ArrayList<Integer>). That may serve the purpose you're looking for. (Supports objects as a type, removal of indexes entirely, etc.)

Comment: `ArrayList<E>`? Isn't that Java? I don't think it's a good idea to go and completely roll my own Undo/Redo system, when I'm sure `NSUndoManager` is optimised to the nines for the task at hand. In the worst case I think that what I'll end up doing is using my own `NSUndoManager` rather than the one that comes attached to the managed object context, and make the core data model changes manually. That way I can still very easily take advantage of the invocation-based undo mechanism. Ideally, of course, I'd like the data model changes to be handled automatically.

Comment: Yeah, it's Java, but I'm trying to provide an example. I'm not too familiar with the iOS development environment, but I'm doing my best to provide something you can port. `ArrayList<E>` is simple enough to write, if you write it specifically for this purpose. Sorry!

As a result, though, I am not entirely certain how `NSUndoManager` works, only how I would write a custom undo/redo program, if the need arose.